# Get Total of office365 license users

Tags: powershell, office365

i am trying to find how many office365 license users by exporting to CSV using the following command

```
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"} | Export-Csv c:\AllUsersWithLicenses.CSV
```

However i got warning message: More results are available. Please very one of the All or MaxResults parameters.

i try this:

```
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"} | Export-Csv c:\AllUsersWithLicenses.CSV -All
```

Error message" A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'All'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it work. I just need to move `-All` after `Get-Msoluser`

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"} | Export-Csv c:\AllUsersWithLicenses.CSV
```